# How to use Highlighted content property pane in my own webpart?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm currently developping my own webpart using Sharepoint Framework. In my webpart property pane I would like to use the exacte same groups as in the "Highlighted content" webparts ( Source and Filter ). I would save some time if it existe somewhere a link to this webpart instead of trying to clone it by myself. 
Thank you in advance for your answers and your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of the out of the box webparts are part of the product itself. And SharePoint is a closed source software.
You will have to rebuild it, [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts) is a link to the samples that might help you get started.

Comment: Ok thank you, do you know how I can manage to dynamically add some properties in the property pane then.  Because even with this.context.propertyPane.refresh(); it doesn't work

Comment: this comment could be a question by itself. Also, don't forget to mark the answer "as answer" :) As far as I know the properyPane.Refresh method only triggers a refresh for the data, but doesn't change the structure of the panel (fields and groups on it) by itself.
I think you'd have to create a custom field that had some more complex logic regarding whether or not adding the controls.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls